# WMTS Layer Syntax for Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I already tried to implement "http://api.ign.fr/tech-docs-js/examples/js/geoportalLeaflet.js, but it does not work for me.

I want to implement the following WMS Tile Layer:

https://www.wmts.nrw.de/geobasis/wmts_nw_dop20

Could someone help me ?

Comment: Please explain in which way it did not work for you. You might also want to take the [tour].

Comment: I defined a simple map with one wmts layer as described below:

Comment: var LuftNRW = new L.tileLayer.wmts('https://www.wmts.nrw.de/geobasis/wmts_nw_dop20?', {
   layer: "nw_dop20",
   attribution: "Data &copy; SW Lemgo",
   format:'image/jpeg',
   tilematrixSet: "EPSG_3857_16"
 });

Comment: map.addLayer(LuftNRW);

Comment: Nothing appears when i initialize the map. What's the correct Syntax?